# Is there any other way to trace a computer besides its IP?

Tags: anonymity, ip

I play on this game thing - it isn't important but it is a roleplay game. I am roleplaying a criminal - a smart one.

Now the fake FBI in the roleplaying game sent me a message. They have made the IP untraceable (in game) so I was wondering if I could roleplay another way to trace where the message came from?

Like broadband connection?

I really don't have a clue - any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The FBI are at

> 935 Pennsylvania Avenue
>
> NW Washington, D.C.
>
> 20535-0001

Big ugly 1970's style building with a lot of flags, between 9th and 10th, you can't miss it.

Comment: Nonresponsive to OP.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.  First, an IP is never untraceable if bi-directional communication is needed.  For TCP, a bi-directional communication is needed.  Thus, a valid IP address must be given.  Now, you can make it difficult to trace by hoping across multiple computers and not having those computers disclose who the previous hop was, but in theory, if you could hack each of those computers, you could still track it back.  This is (basically) how anonymizing networks like TOR work.

There are also many other ways that a system could be potentially tracked.  A trojan on the system could actively report activity of that system if it has been targeted and compromised, though the chances of keeping a persistent infection on an FBI system are probably pretty slim so it might not work for purposes of your game unless they aren't who they claim to be.

Similar to a trojan, if the client is accessing websites, tracking cookies may be accessed by multiple sites to tell if the same user is accessing multiple sites.  This is how lots of targeted advertising works, however in this particular case it sounds like that wouldn't be possible either.

For purposes of your role play, the easiest way would probably be to trace the untraceable IP since it can't really be untraceable, but practically, it would still take a lot of resources and success wouldn't be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your "game thing" is, but be careful. Entrapment is common. If you express an interest in criminal activity, you may find yourself facing serious criminal charges -- and that no one will believe you when you later say that it was all part of a joke or a game.

There really isn't enough information in your question to determine how (or why) you would go about finding this other "player." You could attempt to persuade the player to email or call you outside of the game, which might (or might not) yield a valid IP address, email address, or phone number. You could persuade the player to email or text you a photo, and if you are lucky the photo could contain an EXIF tag with his GPS latitude and longitude.

Real "smart criminals" don't respond at all to communications from law enforcement.

Comment: I think (assuming this is real) he's talking about tracing an attacker in-game.

Answer (score 0):

If you play "this game thing" on a weak operating system (one on which a lot of access control are in `open bar mode` per default) and if you run this
game with a priviledged account, then anything you can read on your system
can also be read through any game. In fact this game has **your** priviledges.

Hence this game **can** get and give your:

1. IP address
2. OS version
3. OS security settings (like firewall off or on)
4. anti-virus settings (is there any, is it alive, is it up to date…)
5. your Outlook saved password
6. your Internet Explorer saved passwords
7. your E-mails, and your Outlook address book
8. your Internet Explorer history
9. … stop here, the list is only limited by **your** actual priviledge.

To answer the original question, one good way to get information on one of the both end of a communication inside a game,
is to go through the weaknesses at the end of the tunnel pretending to obfuscate information (IP addresses):

- the game itself (which will give access to what the player has access to)
  through provided functions, debugging functions, code default…
- the underlying OS (which will also give access to what the player has
  access to).

Comment: I think the OP is looking to discover the other fellow's IP, etc. information rather than to protect his own.

Comment: → user: you are right. But did you notice that the receipe does apply whoever you are: a criminal role playing guy, an FBI agent role playing guy, a totally anonymous user numbered 35648…